# What video HTML5 video formats does the new Blackberry 10 OS support?

Tags: html5-video, h.264, video-encoding, blackberry-10

Blackberry is releasing a new OS (BB10) and smartphone Z10 on January 30th and it is said to have a HTML5 compatible browser, does anyone know which HTML5 video formats it supports. (e.g H.264, WEBM, OGG etc?) I would assume H.264 but looking for confirmation.  Can't find out in any of the Blackberry dev forums.

Answer (score 3):

Blackberry recommendation for optimal local playback is:

**MP4, H.264 High Profile @ 720p (1280x720)**

You can find BB10 Media Supported files here:

https://developer.blackberry.com/devzone/develop/supported_media/bb10_media_support.html

Following link also might be helpful to check:

-Supported streaming protocols
https://developer.blackberry.com/devzone/develop/supported_media/bb10_pbos_streaming_support.html